# How can I replace this pattern with Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to replace all `/` with `\` in all matches of the pattern `src=""` within a string.

I.e., the pattern starts with `src="` and ends with `"`

There could be multiple matches within the string.

I've tried this but it didn't match:

```
"src=\"^*\"$"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
String input = @"...src=""/foo/bar""..";
String output = Regex.Replace(input, "src=\"[^\"]*\"", (m) => m.ToString().Replace('/', '\\'));
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! It works, but how can we treat the \ as an escape character? I tried this (the slashes are to be replaced the other way): String input = @"...src=""/foo/bar"".."; String output = Regex.Replace(input, "src=\"[^\"]*\"", (m) => m.ToString().Replace('/', '\\')); It resulted in output = "...src=\"\\foo\\bar\".."

Comment: @HappyCoder4U: Isn't that the output you wanted? =) These double backslahes are there because a single one would be an escape char. Console.Write(output) would result in `..src="\foo\bar"...`

Comment: Oops. You're right. I was just confused:) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Does your string always end with the closing " ? If not: remove the $ !